# Spark and AWS SDK conflicting version of httpclient

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, httpclient

When running a spark job from a jar, the following error pops up:

```
16/09/22 14:04:41 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.<init>(Ljavax/net/ssl/SSLContext;Ljavax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier;)V
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.<init>(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.getPreferredSocketFactory(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:91)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:65)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.create(ApacheConnectionManagerFactory.java:58)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:51)
    at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.ApacheHttpClientFactory.create(ApacheHttpClientFactory.java:39)
```

It seems that Spark is overwriting the version of httpclient I sent in favor of an older one, thus causing the problem.

What am I missing? How can I force Spark to use the version in my jar instead?

Comment: One of Sparks transitive dependencies uses `HttpClient`. You can shade your assembly in your uber jar. You can see [this post](http://asyncified.io/2016/04/07/spark-uber-jars-and-shading-with-sbt-assembly/) (disclaimer: I'm the author).